# How to loop through all nodes without specifying node names

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I am trying to get all the innerText from all the htmlDocument node from any html document.

I been going doing some research but haven't found a solution to how I will be able to go through all the parent and child node in the entire document without have to specify the node name.

I want to do this because I will be working with different html document so specifying the node name will not be an option for me at this point.

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out now... omg it was so simple to begin with as i didnt know the how to use these function

```
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.Load(MyIO.bingPathToAppDir("Test data/testHTML.html"));
HtmlNode j = htmlDoc.DocumentNode;
foreach (HtmlNode node in j.ChildNodes)
{
    checkNode(node);
}

static void checkNode(HtmlNode node)
{
    foreach (HtmlNode n in node.ChildNodes)
    {
        if (n.HasChildNodes)
        {
            checkNode(n);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(n.InnerText);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following XPath expression to get all non-empty text nodes from arbitrary HTML document without having to know the document structure :

```
//text()[normalize-space()]
```

**Full working console application demo :**

```
var html = @"<p>
   <span>a1</span>
   <span>a2</span>
   <span>b1</span>
   <span>b2</span>
</p>";
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
var result = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()[normalize-space()]");
foreach (var r in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(r.InnerText);
}
```

**<kbd>[`Dotnetfiddle Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rsXpNK)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
a1
a2
b1
b2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also found all nodes like this:

```
string fsURLAddress = "http://www.external-url-sample.com/";

var loHtmlDocument = new HtmlWeb().Load(fsURLAddress);

var loHTMLNodeList = loHtmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Photonic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33032521/107625), I quickly built an extension method:

```
public static class HtmlAgilityPackExtensions
{
    public static void IterateAllNodes(
        this HtmlDocument doc, Action<HtmlNode> action)
    {
        foreach (var n in doc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes)
        {
            doIterateNode(n, action);
        }
    }

    private static void doIterateNode(HtmlNode node, Action<HtmlNode> action)
    {
        action?.Invoke(node);

        foreach (var n in node.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (n.HasChildNodes)
            {
                doIterateNode(n, action);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
doc.IterateAllNodes(
    node =>
    {
        if (node.Name.Equals(@"script", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            node.Remove();
        }
    });
```

This example removes all `<script>` tags and their children.

One could enhance the extension method to not only take an `Action<HtmlNode>` but a `Func<HtmlNode, bool>` to allow the delegate to stop iteration, as soon as `false` is returned.